# Delphi 7 BDE on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, delphi-7, sql-server-2012, bde

Searched the net in and out and could not find proper info on that, we have a legacy setup that uses Delphi 7 and BDE to connect to SQL Server 2005.

Now we are planning to migrate to SQL Server 2012, what are the chances that it might work or not?

Comment: For BDE the chances are reduced to the chances that the new client is backwards compatible with the old client, or the old SQL Client can connect to the new server. Why did you tag this dbExpress?

Comment: The BDE was deprecated a decade ago, and died in the current version of Delphi (it's no longer being included in the distribution), which means you've had at least a decade to replace it with a more modern driver such as ADO. As it will not work with SQL Server 2012, it appears you're going to have to do that replacement now (with a lot less time to do so) in order to do that migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SQL Links MSSQL driver then targeting SQL Server 2012 will not be possible.  The only way that I have been able to use SQL Links with anything newer than SQL Server 2000 is to keep the database compatibility level set to "SQL Server 2000 (80)".  This is not possible in SQL Server 2012.  The oldest compatibility level available in this version is "SQL Server 2005 (90)".

SQL Links will send invalid SQL to the server, such as the "*=" syntax for an outer join.  Databases set for SQL Server 2005 and above will not accept this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using Delphi 7 with SQL Server 2012 without significant issue via the Delphi 7 ADO data control components (e.g. TAdoQuery, TAdoCommand). Stored procedures also work fine, and functions can be called via ADO commands objects (TAdoCommand).

We use the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 ODBC driver that comes with SQL Server 2012. Delphi just treats it as another ODBC data interface. Superficially it looks a lot like using MS Access with Delphi 7 (via ADO components and Access OLE driver). No issue with any of the Service Pack(s?) for SQL Server 2012 either. (Sorry, I don't remember exactly what SP's are released for 2012, but we've had no differences w/ or w/o these SP's, and we tested for it).

Most of the development was done on Windows 7 64-bit OS's, and executed on same as well as Windows Server 2008 and 2008R2, both 64-bit. No special settings were required to execute Delphi-compiled executables (which are all 32-bit, obviously).

If you use ODBC "aliases", be sure to use the 32-bit ODBC DSNs, not the 64-bit ODBC DSNs. The 64-bit ODBC Administrator is the one in the Control Panel\Administrative Tools for 64-bit Windows - don't use it here. Use the 32-bit ODBC Administrator, in Windows' SysWOW64: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. The 64-bit ODBC DSNs live in a separate space from the 32-bit DSNs. Delphi 7 is a 32-bit application and won't have access to the 64-bit DSNs (different API I'm guessing).

We may also have had an issue with comments in SQL statements. I think the line comments ("--") didn't work, but multi-line comments worked ("/*...*/").

Note that while the BDE is preserved by Corel (distributed to this day as the Paradox Runtime; the engine is frozen, however, and does have some issues in modern Windows OS's), it's not needed to access SQL Server data. We use the ODBC aliases directly through the Windows ODBC API (we wrote wrappers in Delphi to make this trivial). However, you can still use the BDE as an interface to these ODBC DSN aliases. If you don't use aliases at all (and don't include any references to DbTables.pas in the source code) you shouldn't need the BDE at all. DbTables.pas initialises the BDE always when it initialises the global Sessions variable in its INTIALIZATION block. You can see this in the bottom of the DbTables.pas source code unit. Without this unit, the BDE isn't initialised or used. (Which also means you cannot use TTable or TQuery components, but those are only for Paradox data; the ADO components like TAdoTable (don't use it unless you want to load the entire data table into memory!), TAdoQuery or TAdoCommand are entirely independent.

Another trick is to use MS Access databases and linked tables to interface between SQL Server and Paradox data tables, if you still need to use BDE-native (i.e. Paradox) tables. But sometimes Access and the BDE don't play well together.

The migration is long done, I'm sure, but in case others are searching for the same answer. Legacy software has a habit of living on...

Answer (score -1):

We've had success using BDE with SQL Server 2008R2. No special config.

Edit: I'm also having initial success on SQL Server 2014 today. Limited testing, but so far so good!

Greg

Comment: The question specifically asks about SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Ken, true but related information is often helpful. At least it always has been for me.

Comment: can you please provide the steps on how you have done it ?